# How to work with @SpringBootApplication and @Configuration, Datasource

Tags: java, spring-boot, firebird

I'm trying to work with a Firebird database and rest capabilities on Spring Boot, but getting: "Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured."

I got an example and made a Spring Appication that connects to a Firebird database. This step is done and working.
Now, I'm trying to add dependencies to provide rest resources. 
So, when I run the app, I'm expecting to retrieve data from Firebird and show it on browser as json.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("br.com.entity")
@EnableJpaRepositories("br.com.repository")
@ComponentScan("br.com.controller")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new 
   AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DataConfiguration.class);
   SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

I´m expecting to retrive data from Firebird and show it on browser as json but it appears to be trying to configure 2 databases. The Firebird database connects but when it run SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args); it starts a new connection that I really dont need and crash.

Comment: You'll have to configure this through your application properties files. THis is typically under src/main/resources. If you say you have an example project working, you should be able to copy the properties from there

Comment: The error you get is in contradiction with your statement that _"[You] made a Spring Appication that connects to a Firebird database. This step is done and working."_. I I were you, I'd start with an introduction on Spring Boot and work your way from there. For example, your code to initialize Spring Boot looks a bit odd. And the error you have can be the result of missing configuration you haven't shown.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I said that it worked with Firebird. Only. On REST implementation, it started to crash.

Comment: That would mean that you used a non-standard Spring Boot configuration for the database settings when you were able to connect to Firebird. If in a standard Spring Boot config you are able to connect to Firebird, then you'll also be able to when adding REST.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rawb.

I did that and it is working like a charm.
This is the main application:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

And this is the config at application.properties

```
## default connection pool
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=20000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=5

## FB
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:firebirdsql://myip:3050//mydb.FDB
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.FirebirdDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```